# How can i change following interface to accept parameters for different types of messaging system. any design pattern ?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
public interface IsendMessage {
public void send(messageContext context);
}
```

Above interface is for sending message. it can be email, SMS , JMS. here method parameter accepts messageContext.

how can i make that generic to accept parameters for all type of messages. like email we have to, from , password, attachement , smtp server properties

But SMS has different properties . so how can i make that interface generic so that. EmailSender and SmsSender can implement this IsendMessage interface to send messages.

Any design pattern can be used here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this have name but i would go with something like this:

```
public interface IsendMessage<T extends MessageContext> {
    public void send(T context);
}

public interface MessageContext {

};

public class SMSMessageContext implements MessageContext{}

public class SMSSender implements IsendMessage<SMSMessageContext>{

    @Override
    public void send(SMSMessageContext context) {

    }

}
```

where your IsendMessage uses generic type of MessageContext.
This way IsendMessage implementation has access to concrete type of MessageContext and its all methods. 
In MessageContext depending on its concrete type you can put anything you need to send message ie: for emails: to, from, topic, for sms: sms text, phone number

Comment: leonz - what goes inside messageContext, like email properties -  to,from